# Prove that there is an infinitely differentiable function $ g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ If $g^{(n)}(0) = n^2 $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Should I use the taylor theorem and get $g(x)$ here? I tried to do that and got that $ g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^2 x^n}{n!}$

Comment: You have the right power series. Do you know the theorem on differentiating a power series term by term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. Now try to see if you can write $g(x)$ as $P(x)e^x$ for some polynomial $P$. In this way you will show that $g$ is an infinitely differentiable function defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note that $n^2=n(n-1)+n$, therefore 
$$g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n(n-1)+n) x^n}{n!}=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n-2)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}\\=x^2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$
Recall that $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ for all real number $x$.

Comment: Instead of splitting $n^2$, if we just write $g(x) = n^2 e^x$, won't that work?

Comment: No. The factor $n^2$ is inside the infinite sum.

Comment: @Rishris: No, because there is no $n$ outside the series.

Comment: This is not necessary if the OP knows that the coefficients of a convergent power series are precisely the Taylor coefficients.

Answer (score 4):

You have done half of the work. Now you have to prove that the radius of convergence of the power series is infinite.

Comment: Just to confirm, proving that radius of convergence is infinite will prove that g(x) exists in all of $\mathbb{R}$. Does that mean that my g(x) above is correct?

Comment: @Rishris : No, that would only be correct if $g$ was to be assumed as analytic around $x=0$. There are non-trivial functions that have all derivatives zero at zero, the type of $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\exp(-\frac1{x^2})$ for $x\ne 0$.